# Переворот таблицы MS SQL

Tags: php, sql-server, table

Всем привет!
Есть такая таблица (допустим, Table_1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо перевернуть её вширь, вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть варианты решить эту задачу?
Может какую-то ХПшку надо с созданием временной таблицы, или на стороне сайта на PHP сделать?

Comment: Если список значений CaseStatisId фиксирован и известен, то PIVOT. Иначе - он же, но динамическим SQL.

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось!